# Use an array in a mysqli prepared statement: `WHERE .. IN(..)` query

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Imagine we have a query:

```
SELECT * FROM somewhere WHERE `id` IN(1,5,18,25) ORDER BY `name`;
```

and an array of IDs to fetch: `$ids = array(1,5,18,25)`

With prepared statements it's [adviced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330268/i-have-an-array-of-integers-how-do-i-use-each-one-in-a-mysql-query-in-php/330280#330280) to prepare one statement and call it multiple times:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM somewhere WHERE `id`=?;');
foreach ($ids as $id){
    $stmt->bind_params('i', $id);
    $stmt->exec();
}
```

But now I'll have to sort the results manually. Do I have any nice alternatives?

Comment: According to the link you provided I think the reasoning for preparing statements was the need to UPDATE which doesn't support multiple updates in one query. Whereas you are SELECTing and so your first query is sufficient.

Comment: I was convinced that prepared statements are not good in such cases. The only nice solution is to 'go one query up' and make this array of IDs sorted there, not here.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

you could do it this way:

```
$ids = array(1,5,18,25);

// creates a string containing ?,?,? 
$clause = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($ids), '?'));


$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM somewhere WHERE `id` IN (' . $clause . ') ORDER BY `name`;');

call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $ids);
$stmt->execute();

// loop through results
```

Using this you're calling bind_param for each id and you have sorting done by mysql.

Comment: Yep, but the bad thing is that the query can't be reused so there's no need to prepare it at all :)

Comment: @o_O Tync: The fewer database trips, the better.  You're welcome to stick to the PreparedStatement constraints, but it won't scale if you need to run 10/20/50/100/1000+ queries to the same table.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just create a view for this statement since it couldn't be reused either way?

Comment: @OMG Ponies, a good point about scaling! Looks like prepared statements can't handle *everything* in an efficient way. Thanks!

Comment: @o_O Tync: Yeah, Prepared Statements are not a silver bullet

Comment: @Ryan Schumacher: Am I missing something?  I don't see what benefit a view would be for passing filtration parameters.  It's just a stored SQL statement...

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Views are just stored SQL statements. I was comparing the use of a prepared statement using static query, but I misread the code. :S Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: This is problematic in php 5.3 for this reason: http://ca.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#96770

Comment: funny how nobody didn't notice input filtering. One of benefits of PDO and this method allows to use it.

Comment: @kolypto Prepared statements aren't just for reuse! They also provide variable binding, which means translation from PHP datatypes to SQL datatypes is handled by your connector (or even database,) which means less thinking and more security. Pure bonus!

Answer (score 18):

Had the same problem and in addition to the answer of @sled 7 years ago, here is a possibility without making the `call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $ids);` step, but only call bind_params once:

```
$ids = array(1,5,18,25);

// creates a string containing ?,?,? 
$bindClause = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($ids), '?'));
//create a string for the bind param just containing the right amount of s 
$bindString = str_repeat('s', count($ids));

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM somewhere WHERE `id` IN (' . $bindClause . ') ORDER BY `name`;');

$stmt->bind_param($bindString, ...$ids);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Very smart code.  What does the three dots before $ids in your code in the bind_params function represent?

Comment: Its called argument unpacking or splat operator. The `bind_params` function takes a variable number of arguments. `...$ids` means, that the array is unpacked in the n-th parameter of the function call.

Comment: can u suggest for a situation with more than one "where in" inside single query?

Comment: @Pankaj it's the same, just use array_merge to put all arrays in one

Comment: @Pankaj Here is [an example of how to set up the placeholders, the query, and the bindings](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql80/0ae0d8b4f91ad0df0ae116f30a50ba9b/php/php8/24604e03f73c6a43ca2b3e1d54580fbc/).

Answer (score 7):

I believe this is the simplest possible answer :

```
$ids = [1,2,3,4,5];
$pdos = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM somwhere WHERE id IN (:"
        . implode(',:', array_keys($ids)) . ") ORDER BY id");

foreach ($ids as $k => $id) {
    $pdos->bindValue(":". $k, $id);
}

$pdos->execute();
$results = $pdos->fetchAll();
```

So long your array of Ids does not contain keys or keys with illegal characters, it wil work.

Comment: Only it's takes twice more code than needed and has nothing to do with mysqli...

Answer (score 5):

For the task of executing a secure mysqli query with a dynamic number of incoming values to be fed into the sql string, a prepared statement is the professional technique to implement.

Let's assume that the incoming data payload is user-supplied data -- this means that we cannot guarantee the integrity of the data nor can we guarantee the volume of data.  In fact, the expected array of data might be empty.  The below snippet will demonstrate how to pass an array of ids to the `IN ()` condition in the `WHERE` clause of a prepared statement.  If there are no values in the array, then a prepared statement provides no benefit and should not be used.

MySQLi result set objects can be immediately iterated by a `foreach()` loop.  Therefore, it is not necessary to make iterated `fetch` calls; just access the rows' data using array syntax.

The array of ids means that the sql will expect integer values.  When calling `bind_param()`, the first parameter will be a single string of repeated `i` characters.  For general use, if the data will be strings or you might have a mix of data types (e.g. integers, floats/doubles, or strings), then is simpler to just use repeated `s` characters instead of `i` characters.

Code: ([PHPize.online Demo with SQL](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql80/0ae0d8b4f91ad0df0ae116f30a50ba9b/php/php8/1939eb37684c6a91ee0942ff0a0a7861/))

```
$ids = [1, 5, 18, 25];  // this could be, for example: $_GET['ids']
$count = count($ids);

$sql = 'SELECT name FROM somewhere';
$orderBy = 'ORDER BY name';
if ($count) {
    $placeholders = implode(',', array_fill(0, $count, '?'));
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("$sql WHERE id IN ($placeholders) $orderBy");
    $stmt->bind_param(str_repeat('i', $count), ...$ids);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
} else {
    $result = $mysqli->query("$sql $orderBy"); // a prepared statement is unnecessary
}
foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo "<div>{$row['name']}</div>\n";
}
```

Output from my PHPize demo:

```
<div>Alan</div>
<div>Bill</div>
<div>Chad</div>
<div>Dave</div>
```

---

If you don't need to iterate the result set for any reason, then you can `fetch_all()`.  This is commonly used when immediately echoing or returning a json-encoded string (say, as the response to an ajax call).  In this case, you replace the `foreach()` block with: ([PHPize.online Demo with SQL](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql80/0ae0d8b4f91ad0df0ae116f30a50ba9b/php/php8/018b90fb409cb2d25d4d1e2415ab0556/))

```
echo json_encode($result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
```

or simply dump the multidimensional array:

```
var_export($result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
```

Output from my PHPize demo:

```
[{"name":"Alan"},{"name":"Bill"},{"name":"Chad"},{"name":"Dave"}]
```

---

From PHP8.1 and higher, it is no longer necessary to call `bind_param()` because the `execute()` method can receive the payload of parameters as an array (like PDO).

This means that...

```
$stmt->bind_param(str_repeat('i', $count), ...$ids);
$stmt->execute();
```

can be replaced with...

```
$stmt->execute($ids);
```

Here's a complete, basic example: ([PHPize.online Demo](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql80/0ae0d8b4f91ad0df0ae116f30a50ba9b/php/php81/13d03e16687ec9f7aeca1ef53346e634/))

```
$ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM somewhere WHERE id IN (" . rtrim(str_repeat('?,', count($ids)), ',') . ") ORDER BY id");
$stmt->execute($ids);
var_export($stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
```

Topical Resources:

- [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php#:%7E:text=Example%20%232%20Execute%20a%20prepared%20statement%20with%20an%20array%20of%20values)
- [The RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysqli_bind_in_execute) was authored by our very own [Dharman ♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1839439/dharman) and [implemented as part of PHP8.1 after a unanimous vote on 2021-03-27](https://php.watch/rfcs/mysqli_bind_in_execute).
- [phpbackend.com article from 24, October 2021](https://phpbackend.com/blog/post/php-8-1-bind-parameters-with-execute-method-in-mysqli#:%7E:text=execute()%20accepts%20a%20parameter%20now)
- [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/llntv5/php_rfc_mysqli_bind_in_execute/)
- [PDO can do this concisely](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql80/0ae0d8b4f91ad0df0ae116f30a50ba9b/php/php8/c0f86da99a30c5a460ac6c47bb98737f/).

Answer (score 2):

I'll add a slow & ugly solution which nevertheless uses prepared statements for ANY number of array items :) 3 statements are universal for any case and can be reused everywhere.

1. `` CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `ids`( `id` INT ); ``
2. `` INSERT INTO `ids` VALUES(?); `` this will insert your IDs
3. `` SELECT `id` FROM `ids` LEFT JOIN .... ; `` use data from other tables to sort the `ids` list
4. `` SELECT `id` FROM `ids`; `` select everything back

Otherwise you'll have to use `IN (?,?,?,....` or sort the rows manually. The best idea is to use simple MySQL-queries, or, try to get the list of IDs already sorted in the way you like.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered rewriting you original query using a JOIN and WHERE clause to get the IDS you need to avoid the need for a WHERE IN clause? I came here with the same question and after reviewing the possible solutions I realized an INNER JOIN was my solution.

Comment: That was the internal logic: the app needed to fetch N users by id, provided externally. Glad that your case turned out to be not so specific :)

Answer (score 0):

Copied from my answer here [How to use PDO prepared statements with IN clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37827340)

using named place holders

```
$values = array(":val1"=>"value1", ":val2"=>"value2", ":val2"=>"$value3");
$statement = 'SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE `column` in(:'.implode(', :',array_keys($values)).') ORDER BY `column`';
```

using ??

```
$values = array("value1", "value2", "$value3");
$statement = 'SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE `column` in('.trim(str_repeat(', ?', count($values)), ', ').')  ORDER BY `column`';
```

Comment: I was struggling with this using Phalcon, and the bottom option solved it for me!

Answer (score -1):

An alternative would be to use PHP usort function on the result object, but this is "manual."

See this:
[Sort Object in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124266/sort-object-in-php)