# Delete Multiple Selected Data in PHP/MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, crud

Good day, I've seen a couple of threads with similar questions but I can't seem to implement the suggestions on my practice project.

is there any way I can add a function where my selected items can be deleted at once?

Here are my codes.

select.php

```php
<?php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "appointments");  
 $output = '';  
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM appointments ORDER BY id DESC";  
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
 $output .= '  
      <div class="table-responsive">  
           <table class="table table-bordered">  
                <tr>  
                     <th width="5%">Checkbox</th>
                     <th width="10%">Id</th>  
                     <th width="40%">Name</th>  
                     <th width="40%">Email</th>  
                     <th width="40%">Address</th>  
                     <th width="10%">phoneNumber</th>  
                     <th width="10%">appointmentTime</th> 
                     <th width="10%">appointmentDate</th> 
                     <th width="50%">message</th> 
                     <th width="10%">delete</th> 
                </tr>';  
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
 {  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {  
           $output .= '


                <tr>  

                     </td>
                     <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>

                     <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>
                     <td class="name" data-id1="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["name"].'</td>  
                     <td class="email" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["email"].'</td>
                     <td class="address" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["address"].'</td>  
                     <td class="phoneNumber" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["phoneNumber"].'</td>  
                     <td class="appointmentTime" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["appointmentTime"].'</td>  
                     <td class="appointmentDate" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["appointmentDate"].'</td>
                     <td class="message" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["message"].'</td>
                     <td><button type="button" name="delete_btn" data-id3="'.$row["id"].'" class="btn btn-danger                             btn_delete">Delete</button></td>   
                </tr>  
           ';  
      }  
 }  
 else  
 {  
      $output .= '<tr>  
                          <td colspan="10"><center><p style="color:red">No Data Found</p></center></td>  
                     </tr>';  
 }  
 $output .= '</table>  
      </div>';  
 echo $output;  
 ?>
```

Here's the delete function for a single row.

```html
 <?php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "appointments");  
 $sql = "DELETE FROM appointments WHERE id = '".$_POST["id"]."'";  
 if(mysqli_query($connect, $sql))  
 {  
      echo 'Data Deleted';  
 }  
 ?>
```

Here's my display page.

```html
<?php
    require("config.php");
    if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) 
    {
        header("Location: success.php");
        die("Redirecting to index.php"); 
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Simple Sidebar - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 


</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand">
                    <a href="#">
                        Hope Medi Clinic
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="../../appointments/">Main Website</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

        <!-- Page Content -->
                   <div class="container">  
                <br />  
                <br />  
                <br />  
                <div class="table-responsive">  
                     <h3 align="center">Appointments</h3><br />  
                     <div id="live_data"></div>
                     <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
                </div>  
           </div>  
        <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

    </div>

    <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){
      function fetch_data()  
      {  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"select.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#live_data').html(data);  
                }  
           });  
      }  
      fetch_data();  


      function edit_data(id, text, column_name)  
      {  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"edit.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{id:id, text:text, column_name:column_name},
                dataType:"text",  
                success:function(data){  
                     alert(data);  
                }  
           });  
      }  

     /* ............. */
      $(document).on('blur', '.name', function(){  
           var id = $(this).data("id1");  
           var name = $(this).text();  
           edit_data(id, name, "name");  
      });  

      $(document).on('blur', '.email', function(){  
           var id = $(this).data("id2");  
           var email = $(this).text();  
           edit_data(id, email, "email");  
      });
     $(document).on('blur', '.address', function(){  
           var id = $(this).data("id2");  
           var address = $(this).text();  
           edit_data(id, address, "address");  
      });
     $(document).on('blur', '.phoneNumber', function(){  
           var id = $(this).data("id2");  
           var phoneNumber = $(this).text();  
           edit_data(id, phoneNumber, "phoneNumber");  
      });
     $(document).on('blur', '.appointmentTime', function(){  
           var id = $(this).data("id2");  
           var appointmentTime = $(this).text();  
           edit_data(id, appointmentTime, "appointmentTime");  
      });
     $(document).on('blur', '.appointmentDate', function(){  
           var id = $(this).data("id2");  
           var appointmentDate = $(this).text();  
           edit_data(id, appointmentDate, "appointmentDate");  
      });
     $(document).on('blur', '.message', function(){  
           var id = $(this).data("id2");  
           var message = $(this).text();  
           edit_data(id, message, "message");  
      });

      $(document).on('click', '.btn_delete', function(){  
           var id=$(this).data("id3");  
           if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?"))  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"delete.php",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:{id:id},  
                     dataType:"text",  
                     success:function(data){  
                          alert(data);  
                          fetch_data();  
                     }  
                });  
           }  
      });  
 });

 </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: _Here's the delete function for a single row._?? Where?

Comment: oh. -.- sorry, but I doubt it would work with multiple lol .

Comment: I think you have some problem with your data table. Check you use `<button type="button" name="delete_btn".....` two times.

Comment: And this is not a form and a link so how can you operate the delete operation?

Comment: The table functions over Javascript / AJAX. However, the second delete button is purely php, and it's for a singular row. The first button you see, is the button I want to use to delete the selected rows.

Comment: both the button has same class name `btn_delete`, so how can you differ??

Comment: bro, like I said - the first button is nothing at the moment. I'll edit it to make it clear. :)

Comment: write check box for each item and then get id from the check box. delete through the id. sounds simple.

Comment: So for now you need only the single row.

Comment: The single row delete function is working. No need to fix that.. It's the multiple delete option I'm trying to get.

Comment: @Frayne it already has a checkbox for each item :) . PS. the posted codes are just snippets of the entire thing.

Comment: So what about _he first button is nothing at the moment._???

Comment: I updated the post for you to see.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how you are sending the data from the HTML to the PHP page in this example, so I will give you a generic simple implementation and hopefully you can figure out how to work it into your project.

**HTML:**
Using checkboxes, you can send multiple values as an array to a php script like so.

```
<form action="delete.php" method="POST">
    <input name="delete[]" value="id_of_row" type="checkbox">
    <input name="delete[]" value="id_of_another_row" type="checkbox">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This will send an array of whatever is in the `value` attribute of each box that is checked. You would then be able to delete every row that was checked with the following php script.

**PHP:**

```
<?php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "appointments");  
 foreach($_POST['delete'] as $id){
     $sql = "DELETE FROM appointments WHERE id = '" . $id . "';  
     if(mysqli_query($connect, $sql))  
     {  
          echo 'Data Deleted';  
     }
 }  
 ?>
```

This should be what you need to somehow implement into your existing project so that you can delete multiple rows at once.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't post the main page. It's all AJAX / Jquery on the display page, so I opt not to post it :) The code posted above is called by AJAX to fill in a DIV. Just didn't post it because I needed a php solution, people might recommend javascript hehe

Comment: Btw, thanks - I'll try this in a sec and post my feedback.

Comment: doesn't work ;( maybe it's because I'm using ajax for the other functions (CRUD)

Comment: nvm, redid everything and added this :) Worked. thanks -- this leaves me with more questions lol . Anyway, thanks

Answer (score 1):

It will be cleaner and more professional to send an array of ids to your php file as suggested by earlier answers:

```
<input name="ids[]" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" type="checkbox">
```

...then make just one trip to the database to delete multiple rows.

```
if (
    empty($_POST['ids'])
    // || array_filter($_POST['ids'], function($v) { return !ctype_digit($v); })
) {
    exit('Missing/Invalid data submitted');  // be deliberately vague
}

$connect = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "appointments");
$count = count($_POST['ids']);
$stmt = $connect->prepare(
    sprintf(
        "DELETE FROM appointments WHERE id IN (%s)",
        implode(',', array_fill(0, $count, '?'))  // e.g if 3 ids, then "?,?,?"
    )
);
$stmt->bind_param(str_repeat('i', $count), ...$_POST['ids']);
$stmt->execute();
printf('Deleted %d row(s)', $stmt->affected_rows());
```

This resembles a similar post of mine: [<kbd>SELECT with dynamic number of values in IN()</kbd>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71718174/2943403)

Answer (score -1):

You should be using array for this.

```
 <td><input type="checkbox" name='check[]' value=".$row['id']." /></td>
```

and in delete function you should be doing something like this.

```
<?php  
 $connect = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "appointments"); 
 $totalCheckboxChecked = sizeof($_POST['check']);
      for($i=0;$i<$totalCheckboxChecked;$i++)
            {
             $idToDelete = $check[$i];
             $sql = "DELETE FROM appointments WHERE id = $idToDelete";  
             $result=$connect->query($sql);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Mind if I ask? How should I do the button to delete? Seems like the buttons I make won't work. Maybe because I use javascript with the table?

Comment: You should have checkbox to all the values and a submit button so that you can check the values and submit.

Comment: damn still doesn't work, I might just redo everything for it to be compatible to a tutorial I'm trying -.-

Comment: I am not sure how you are submitting that checked data.  Submit button is required i guess.

Comment: Change this :   <td><button type="button" name="delete_btn" data-id3="'.$row["id"].'" class="btn btn-danger                             btn_delete">Delete</button></td>  to   <td><button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-danger                             btn_delete">Delete</button></td> @nathan

Comment: Sure, I'll try thanks. It's the ajax code that's submitting.