# Convert array into a SQL query securely (PHP7+PDO+SQLite)

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

Using PHP7+PDO+SQLite, I am looking for a way to filter the entries in a table using a user-defined filter in the form of an array generated on the frontend. For clarity, here is an example of what I'm looking for:

**The Example**:

Table in the database:

```
 ID             Firstname      Lastname       Age
+--------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
| 0            | John         | Doe          | 21          |
| 1            | John         | Smith        | 35          |
| 2            | Alice        | Smith        | 35          |
| 3            | Bob          | Smith        | 40          |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
```

Filters:

```php
/*
Filters follow the structure:
[
    "Table Column Name 1" => [Match1 OR Match2 OR ...],
    AND
    "TCN 2" ...
]
Any column name not provided should match any value.
*/

[
    "Firstname" => ["John"]
]
// ^ fetchAll() returns rows with ID 0 and 1

[
    "Firstname" => ["John", "Alice"],
    "Lastname" => ["Smith"]
]
// ^ ID 1 and 2 (but not 3)
```

I need to find a function which can convert the arrays above into a SQL query to fetch all rows which match the filter. I would like to do this using SQL (which I don't have much experience with) instead of fetching all rows and filtering them with PHP for performance reasons.

I know that I can do something along the lines of:

```php
// Untested - for illustration purposes only

$filter = [
    "Firstname" => ["John", "Alice"],
    "Lastname" => ["Smith"]
];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE ";

foreach ($filter as $column => $matching_values) {

    foreach ($matching_values as $match) {

        $sql .= $column . " == " . $match . " OR ";

    }

    // Ugly way of removing trailing ` OR `
    $sql = substr($sql, 0, -4);

    $sql .= " AND ";

}
// Ugly way of removing trailing ` AND `
$sql = substr($sql, 0, -5);

echo $sql;
```

But this introduces a massive SQL injection security flaw. I want to know if there is a simple yet efficient and secure way to achieve this. The format of the filters can also be changed if required, for example to RegEx (bonus points if someone can replace the innermost arrays in the examples above with RegEx).

Alternatively (or additionally), a simple way to describe my problem in a searchable way might be helpful since I couldn't do much research about this because I couldn't word it well.

Comment: How's your homework on using PDO and prepared statements? Please add into the post what you've tried, using PDO, and what the problems are. As far as the data in your array, here is no high-end function to be found here, just basic array operations.

Comment: You may find it handy to use `WHERE ... IN` instead of spelling out a hundred ORs for possible values per column. As in, `WHERE Firstname IN ('John', 'Alice')` etc. https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-in/

Comment: @MarkusAO Actually, it's not a homework but a project. Here's the link: https://github.com/TR-SLimey/wraith . Specifically for the indev branch. I believe you have mistaken me for one of your students? :)

Comment: Topically related, but not as complex: [Use an array in a mysqli prepared statement: `WHERE .. IN(..)` query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71718174/2943403). Note that if you don't have any conditions (the array was empty), then you won't need a prepared statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will be an interesting combination of several techniques I am teaching on my site already, namely

- [creating WHERE clause dynamically](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/dynamical_where)
- [creating a prepared statement for IN clause](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#in)
- [whitelisting](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/order_by) to protect from [SQL injection](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/sql_injection_example)

In the end it will be something like this

```
$allowed = ["Firstname", "Lastname"];

$conditions = [];
$parameters = [];
foreach ($filter as $key => $values) {
    if (!in_array($key, $allowed, true)) { 
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("invalid field name!"); 
    }
    $conditions[] = sprintf(
        "`%s` IN (%s)",
        $key,
        str_repeat('?,', count($values) - 1) . '?'
    );
    array_push($parameters, ...$values);
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
if ($conditions)
{
    $sql .= " WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $conditions);
}
```

will produce a query you are looking for,

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE `Firstname` IN (?,?) AND `Lastname` IN (?)
```

as well as an array of values to be used in `PDO::execute()`, making a bullet proof solution where values are protected via parameters and filed names  protected from via filtering against a white list

My only doubt is that the case present in the question could be oversimplified. As soon as you will need not only exact matching, but partial matching or greater/less comparison the complexity of the code will skyrocket.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I currently cannot test it but will as soon as I can and then I'll accept it :-)

Comment: Not that I am craving a tick, but [you can, actually](https://3v4l.org/iEhUK)

Comment: Thanks for the link but I couldn't test it because I had a phonecall to make not because I didn't have a testing environment :P
 I will now test it and get back to you :)
 Also, I was wondering if SQLite supports RegExes at all? So for example I can specify a RegEx instead of allowed options? I can add that to the function myself but maybe you can give some tips?

Comment: Other than the above, this seems like just what I am looking for. Thank you! Accepted answer.

Comment: Honestly I don't see how an SQLite supported RegEx could help here at all. Accessing any SQLite functionality means a query already executed. With all its wanted or unwanted contents.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean. To clarify, I'm asking whether it's possible to include RegEx in a SQL query, so, for example, `WHERE column_name MATCHES /RegEx/` or something like that.

Comment: I mean that if you check against SQL injection *inside* the SQL query then you already got it injected. Given column_name can be a malicious SQL ended with a comment it will never reach no regex. So to put it short - you should verify the column names **before** the query execution

Comment: Ahhh, I see the misunderstanding. What I meant by allowed options was replacing the filters (`["Matching option 1", "Matching option 2"]`) which I referred to as allowed options with RegEx. Only now I realised that you've used the word "allowed" to describe the whitelist in your code.