# Compare multidimensional arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, compare

How can I compare multidimensional arrays in php? Is there a simple way?

Comment: [PHP - Check if two arrays are equal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5678990/6521116)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The simplest way I know:

```
$a == $b;
```

Note that you can also use the `===`. The difference between them is:

1. With **Double equals** `==`, order is important:

   ```
   $a = array(0 => 'a', 1 => 'b');
   $b = array(1 => 'b', 0 => 'a');
   var_dump($a == $b);  // true
   var_dump($a === $b); // false
   ```
2. With **Triple equals** `===`, types matter:

   ```
   $a = array(0, 1);
   $b = array('0', '1');
   var_dump($a == $b);  // true
   var_dump($a === $b); // false
   ```

**Reference: [Array operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php)**

Comment: This will not compare the order & types of array's elements.

Comment: But: `array(0, 1) != array(1, 0)`, so it depends on the keys/index.

Comment: @DanMan It wouldn't make much sense if `array(0, 1) == array(1, 0)` were true, would it?

Comment: @DanMan Sounds like you want to use a [set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type%29). PHP doesn't have a built-in set type, but you can create one. The order of elements is very important in an array.

Answer (score 13):

Another way to do it is to `serialize()` both of the arrays and compare the strings.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: i was looking for a solution in C# & PowerShell. You are my savior :D

Comment: Beware of array order with serialize.  `serialize(['a'=>'foo', 'b'=>'bar']) != serialize(['b'=>'bar', 'a'=>'foo'])`

Answer (score 13):

This function will do it all for you.

You can use it to truly compare any **2 arrays of same or totally different structures**.

It will return:

> Values in **array1** not in **array2** *(more)*
>
> Values in **array2** not in **array1** *(less)*
>
> Values in array1 and in array2 but **different** *(diff)*

```
//results for array1 (when it is in more, it is in array1 and not in array2. same for less)
function compare_multi_Arrays($array1, $array2){
    $result = array("more"=>array(),"less"=>array(),"diff"=>array());
    foreach($array1 as $k => $v) {
      if(is_array($v) && isset($array2[$k]) && is_array($array2[$k])){
        $sub_result = compare_multi_Arrays($v, $array2[$k]);
        //merge results
        foreach(array_keys($sub_result) as $key){
          if(!empty($sub_result[$key])){
            $result[$key] = array_merge_recursive($result[$key],array($k => $sub_result[$key]));
          }
        }
      }else{
        if(isset($array2[$k])){
          if($v !== $array2[$k]){
            $result["diff"][$k] = array("from"=>$v,"to"=>$array2[$k]);
          }
        }else{
          $result["more"][$k] = $v;
        }
      }
    }
    foreach($array2 as $k => $v) {
        if(!isset($array1[$k])){
            $result["less"][$k] = $v;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: I've tested your function and got as 'more' a value under an existing key. Yo must use `array_key_exists($k, $array2[$k])` instead the test `isset($array2[$k])` because isset tests the key exists and **has a not null value**.

Comment: I have a misstype . I must wrote `array_key_exists($k, $array2)`

Comment: I use this function in production and never had an issue. If you find a way of improving it please let me know. Thanks @quevedo

Comment: You mention that your function will work with "2 arrays of same or totally different structures." I have two arrays and I have tried every conversion I am aware of but none are working in your function. It prints the expected three arrays (more/less/diff) but they are empty. Here is a partial example of my array format: Array1 ([{"id":"100000565","position":"Cost Containment Analyst","area":"Warehouse (Domestic US)","ro":"","span":"0",) and Array2([{"id":"100000567","position":"Global Logistics Specialist","area":"Shipping/Receiving","ro":1,"span":).

Comment: Works perfectly comparing multidimensional arrays! Well done @Kareem !

Answer (score 2):

```
function multi_diff($arr1,$arr2){
  $result = array();
  foreach ($arr1 as $k=>$v){
    if(!isset($arr2[$k])){
      $result[$k] = $v;
    } else {
      if(is_array($v) && is_array($arr2[$k])){
        $diff = multi_diff($v, $arr2[$k]);
        if(!empty($diff))
          $result[$k] = $diff;
      }
    }
  }
  return $result;
}

//example:

var_dump(multi_diff(

array(
  "A"=>array(
    "A1"=>array('A1-0','A1-1','A1-2','A1-3'),
    "A2"=>array('A2-0','A2-1','A2-2','A2-3'),
    "A3"=>array('A3-0','A3-1','A3-2','A3-3')
  ),
  "B"=>array(
    "B1"=>array('B1-0','B1-1','B1-2','B1-3'),
    "B2"=>array('B2-0','B2-1','B2-2','B2-3'),
    "B3"=>array('B3-0','B3-1','B3-2','B3-3')
  ),
  "C"=>array(
    "C1"=>array('C1-0','C1-1','C1-2','C1-3'),
    "C2"=>array('C2-0','C2-1','C2-2','C2-3'),
    "C3"=>array('C3-0','C3-1','C3-2','C3-3')
  ),
  "D"=>array(
    "D1"=>array('D1-0','D1-1','D1-2','D1-3'),
    "D2"=>array('D2-0','D2-1','D2-2','D2-3'),
    "D3"=>array('D3-0','D3-1','D3-2','D3-3')
  )
),

array(
  "A"=>array(
    "A1"=>array('A1-0','A1-1','A1-2','A1-3'),
    "A2"=>array('A2-0','A2-1','A2-2','A2-3'),
    "A3"=>array('A3-0','A3-1','A3-2')
  ),
  "B"=>array(
    "B1"=>array('B1-0','B1-2','B1-3'),
    "B2"=>array('B2-0','B2-1','B2-2','B2-3'),
    "B3"=>array('B3-0','B3-1','B3-3')
  ),
  "C"=>array(
    "C1"=>array('C1-0','C1-1','C1-2','C1-3'),
    "C3"=>array('C3-0','C3-1')
  ),
  "D"=>array(
    "D1"=>array('D1-0','D1-1','D1-2','D1-3'),
    "D2"=>array('D2-0','D2-1','D2-2','D2-3'),
    "D3"=>array('D3-0','D3-1','D3-2','D3-3')
  )
)

));
```

Comment: Some explanation of logic would make a nicer answer :)

Comment: This will not handle X by X  it is only one level deep

Comment: Also won't handle if the second array has more elements than the first. Identical issue to the function this was copied from <grin>

Comment: You don't need to call the function inside itself you should call array_intersect($v, $arr2[$k]); inside the function it will compare the array and return a single array to you.

Answer (score 0):

To compare array's structure, You should use identity operator.

```
if($arrayA === $arrayB) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: The only difference(s) between this and my answer is that instead of using `==` for the elements in the array, it will use `===`, and with `===` it checks the order of key value pairs. From what I understood from the question, the OP wants `==`, **NOT** `===`. And I also put a link on my answer if the OP is interested in that.

Comment: One symbol here makes a lot of difference.

Comment: So you are telling me that given `$a = array(1 => 'a', 0 => 'b'); $b = array(0 => 'b', 1 => 'a');`, the OP wants something that would return false? Interesting.

Comment: Author wants "to compare if they (arrays) have exactly the same content and the same structure". Check the PHP example : $b = array(1 => "banana", "0" => "apple"); var_dump($a == $b); // bool(true) var_dump($a === $b); // bool(false)

Comment: Hy Guys, thanks for help. But you only tell me the way to compare one dimensional arrays. But how about compare two or three dimensional arrays? Like Example :`a = array(1 => 'a', 0 => array(1 => 'b')); ` and `$b = array(1 => "banana", "0" => array(0 => 'apple'));` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$difference = array();
foreach($array1 as $key => $value)
{
    if(is_array($value))
    {
        if(!isset($array2[$key]))
        {
            $difference[$key] = $value;
        }
        elseif(!is_array($array2[$key]))
        {
            $difference[$key] = $value;
        }
        else
        {
            $new_diff = array_diff($value, $array2[$key]);
            if($new_diff != FALSE)
            {
                $difference[$key] = $new_diff;
            }
        }
    }
    elseif(!isset($array2[$key]) || $array2[$key] != $value)
    {
        $difference[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```