# Multidimensional arrays comparison in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

When comparing arrays [The Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) says

> $a == $b  Equality    TRUE if $a and $b have the same key/value pairs.

Though when comparing with multidimensional arrays this doesn’t seem to be the case

```
$a = array(
  array("test"),
  array("testing"),
);
$b = array(
  array("testing"),
  array("test"),
);

var_dump($a);
var_dump($b);
var_dump($a == $b);
```

returns

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(4) "test"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(7) "testing"
  }
}
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(7) "testing"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(4) "test"
  }
}
bool(false)
```

Same array, Different order. array diff returns correctly though.

Is this an expected feature ? I know i can compare with array_diff($a,b) + array($b, $a). Im not sure why the `==` doesnt work though

Comment: Because of the integer keys. Your array is basically `array( 0 => array("test"), 1 => array("testing"))` and `array( 0 => array("testing"), 1 => array("test") );` - which are not the same.

Comment: Argh completely overlooked that, If you make that an answer ill accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your arrays are different in the leaf nodes.

In your first array `0` = `test` and in your second array `0` = `testing`.

Answer (score 0):

Use === comparison for taking care about keys order.

Check this source:

[Compare multidimensional arrays in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389176/compare-multidimensional-arrays-in-php)

regards

Answer (score 0):

`==` sign allows for comparison of arrays in any order, it will internally use a sort on the master array and do the `===` comparision.

However it does not do a sort on the sub-arrays, you will need to do that manually before the comparison

**NOTE** : see == & === difference [details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5678990/724913)