# PHP check if arrays are identical?

Tags: php

I'm looking for a way to check if two arrays are identical, for example

```
  $a = array(
    '1' => 12,
    '3' => 14,
    '6' => 11
);
$b = array(
    '1' => 12,
    '3' => 14,
    '6' => 11
);
```

These two would be identical, but if a single value was changed, it would return false, I know I could write a function, but is there one already built?

Comment: But if a single value was changed then they wouldn't be identical. What's the question here?

Comment: Did you even try just using `===`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Check if two arrays are equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678959/php-check-if-two-arrays-are-equal)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use

```
$a === $b // or $a == $b
```

example of usage:

```
<?php
$a = array(
    '1' => 12,
    '3' => 14,
    '6' => 11
);
$b = array(
    '1' => 12,
    '3' => 14,
    '6' => 11
);
echo ($a === $b) ? 'they\'re same' : 'they\'re different';

echo "\n";
$b['1'] = 11;

echo ($a === $b) ? 'they\'re same' : 'they\'re different';
```

which will return

```
they're same
they're different
```

[demo](http://codepad.org/sb1eSUNA)

Comment: This answer is misleading to people coming in from search. `array_diff` does not work very well for checking for "identical arrays." It also has a premise that the keys will not change. Adding another key, with one of the existing values, will not work with array_diff, also adding a value to the first array or the second array gives different results.

Comment: @DustinGraham: can you show me a demo of what you mean? I'm a bit confused with this

Comment: If a person arrives here looking for a way to tell if two arrays are identical, the answer (yours) has the first suggestion of `array_diff()` which can be misleading, try this: `$a = array('x' => true, 'y' => false); $b = array('x' => true, 'y' => true, 'z' => false); print_r(array_diff($a,$b));` Clearly they are not identical, but `array_diff` shows no differences.

Comment: Works for subarrays too.

Answer (score 30):

You can just use `$a == $b` if order doesn't matter, or `$a === $b` if order does matter.

For example:

```
$a = array(
    '1' => 12,
    '3' => 14,
    '6' => 11
);
$b = array(
    '1' => 12,
    '3' => 14,
    '6' => 11
);
$c = array(
    '3' => 14,
    '1' => 12,
    '6' => 11
);
$d = array(
    '1' => 11,
    '3' => 14,
    '6' => 11
);

$a == $b;   // evaluates to true
$a === $b;  // evaluates to true
$a == $c;   // evaluates to true
$a === $c;  // evaluates to false
$a == $d;   // evaluates to false
$a === $d;  // evaluates to false
```