# How can I compare two arrays of data retrieve from database?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have two arrays. In one array, I store data from one table. I store data from another table in the other array. I wanted to compare data from both of the arrays. If the data of the first array is in the second array, I want to proceed. How can I perform this?

I tried the following code but it's not working event though the array1 number exists in array2:

```
$x = "SELECT * FROM table1";
$data1 = mysqli_query($link, $x);
$dat1 = array()
while($row1= mysqli_fetch_array($data,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
  $dat1[] = $row1;
  $f1 = $row1['fid'];
}

$y = "SELECT * FROM table2";
$data2 = mysqli_query($link, $y);
$dat2 = array()
while($row2= mysqli_fetch_array($data2,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
  $dat2[] = $row2;
  $f2 = $row2['fid'];
}

if(in_array($dat1,$dat2))
{
  // if exists proceed
}
else
{
  // if not show error
}
```

Comment: Please provide a positive and negative example. Note that you've misspelled `$dat2` as `$dta2` in your code.

Comment: Asker, is the `$dta2` in `if(in_array($data,$dta2))` a typo?

Comment: haa its just a typo...let data1 = 1, 2,3 and data2= 1 when i check for `if(atleast one of data2 matches with data1)                                       {  //procesed   }else { //show error}`

Comment: @Thauwa Definitely, it's a typo. I fixed it.

Comment: You can't compare them, using in_array function. Because it is supposed to deal with 1-dimensional arrays. And you have 2-dimentional arrays. You need to loop though them and compare. But this will work only if your arrays are sorted in the same manner

Comment: I would suggest to optimize it. You can check sizes and other features  of  its elements before running heavy operations.  This might increase performance.

Comment: I changed $data to $dat1 in the last `if` to fix the 2-nd typo

Comment: possible duplicate of [in\_array() and multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128323/in-array-and-multidimensional-array)

Comment: maybe you need to do this: in_array($dat1, array($dat2))

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459315/php-compare-2-multidimensional-arrays-and-output-values-if-equal-fields-in-arr

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by SQL.

To check if all fids in table1 are in table2:

```
SELECT COUNT(a.fid) FROM table1 AS a WHERE a.fid IN (SELECT b.fid FROM table2 AS b)

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1
```

If the two values are equal, then all fids in table1 are in table2.

Answer (score 0):

According to your last comment your logic is wrong in your code then. You are currently pulling all rows into your $dat1 variable from your mysql return so you would not be able to check if a specific value exists in the 2nd array by using the entire array as a single value. You are also overwriting $f1 on each iteration of your while loop.

You could check this for each ID returned from your first array like this.

```
$x = "SELECT * FROM table1";
$data1 = mysqli_query($link, $x);
$dat1 = array()
while($row1= mysqli_fetch_array($data,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
  $dat1[] = $row1;
  $f1 = $row1['fid'];
  $y = "SELECT * FROM table2 where fid = ".$f1;
  $data2 = mysqli_query($link, $y);
  $dat2 = array();
  while($row2= mysqli_fetch_array($data2,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
  {
    //data exists in table2
  }
}
```

Comment: no they are not exactly identical just wanted to check if $dat1 if existing $dat2

Answer (score 0):

```
if(in_array($data,$dat2))
{
  //if exists proceed
}
else
{
  //if not show error
}
```

why do you put $data here ? should be $dat1 no ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way

```
 $bool=0;
 foreach ($dat1 as $a) {
    foreach ($dat2 as $b) {
        if($a==$b)
        {
            $bool=1;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            $bool=0;
        }
    }
    if($bool==1)
    {
        break;
    }
 }
 if($bool==1)
 {
   //proceed
  }
 else
  {
     //error
   }
```

Here if anyone of the value in dat2 is present in dat1 then it will be true and you can proceed.

Answer (score 0):

As sotirojo just pointed out, don't try to do data stuff in PHP when you can do it in a database!
So any answer that tells you how to solve your issue within PHP in my eyes will be a wrong answer.

```
SELECT table_1.* 
   FROM table_1
   JOIN table_2 USING(fid)
```

Will return you all rows that exist in both table_1 as table_2

```
SELECT table_1.* 
   FROM table_1
   LEFT JOIN table_2 USING(fid)
WHERE table_2.fid IS NULL
```

Will return you all rows in table_1 that are not in table_2

And so on.

Use your database for doing data things.

Answer (score 0):

putting aside the sql part, use this function:

```
function compare_array($arr1,$arr2)
{
    foreach($element as $arr1)
    {    
        foreach($element2 as $arr2)
        {
            if($element2 == $element)
            {
               return true;
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
 return false;
}
```

pass it your two arrays obtained with your queries and act upon its return
it might be a bit heavy but if I understand well what you need it should work

Answer (score 0):

According to:  SQL for Dummies, the INNER JOIN discards all rows from the result table that DO NOT have corresponding rows in both source tables.

Try:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;
```