# check if an multidimensional array's every element can be finded in another multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, laravel-5

For example,I want to check if every element in "search_this" array can be finded in "all" array (it means the all array has the same value element).

```
  $search_this = Array
(
(0) => Array
    (
        (id) => '1',
        (name) => 'a'
    ),

(1) => Array
    (
        (id) => '2',
        (name) => 'b'
    ),

(2) => Array
    (
        (id) => '3',
        (name) => 'c'
    )
);

$all = Array
(
(0) => Array
    (
        (id) => '1',
        (name) => 'a'
    ),

(1) => Array
    (
        (id) => '2',
        (name) => 'd'
    ),

(2) => Array
    (
        (id) => '4',
        (name) => 'c'
    )
);
```

like this ↑　, only one element can be find in "all" array ,not all.
thus the result is false.

is there any function in php which can do this?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678959/php-check-if-two-arrays-are-equal

Comment: $search_this== $all  Equality TRUE if $search_this and $all   have the same key/value pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@chii you can directly check with == operator like:

```
<?php
  $result = $search_this == $all; //return true or false, check only values of the element not data type of element
  $result = $search_this === $all; //return true or false, check both values and data type of the element
```

Comment: thank you, I used it and it worked well . but I found the == operator also check the array key, accutualy i have the two array with different key (but the same value),so i did someting to let the key be the same and it worked.

Comment: == check both key and value but it does not check the data type of key and value of an array but ===  also check the data type of key and value

Answer (score 0):

```
$inArray = array();
foreach ($search_this as $search){
    if(in_array($search, $all)){
        $inArray[]=$search;
    }
}
print_r($inArray);
```

result of printing

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
           [name] => a
        )
)