# How to check if two arrays are the same?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I want to check if two arrays are identical. Normally everybody just would use something like this:

```
if($arrayA == $arrayB){
   //do something...
}
```

But my question is, how can I check, if the array contains the same values?

For example, array A looks like:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    ["price"]=>
    string(5) "50"
    ["shop"]=>
    string(4) "9509"
  }
  [1]=>
    array(6) {
    ["price"]=>
    string(5) "5"
    ["shop"]=>
    string(4) "9509"
  }
}
```

and array B look like:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    ["price"]=>
    string(5) "5"
    ["shop"]=>
    string(4) "9509"
  }
  [1]=>
    array(6) {
    ["price"]=>
    string(5) "50"
    ["shop"]=>
    string(4) "9509"
  }
}
```

As you can see, only the inner arrays have swaped (5 & 50). But I want to get true. I just want to know if both arrays contain the same informations. Not, if they are completely identical!

How can I check this?

Greetings and Thank You!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678959/php-check-if-two-arrays-are-equal

Comment: If you would've checked the manual. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php

Answer (score 0):

It sound like your arrays contain different types of data inside, that's not a recommended implementation.

My recommendation my friend is to create an object with all the properties you need and then you can override the method `compare` extending the interface `comparable`.

If still you want to compare arrays, try `Arrays.equals(arr1, arr2)` but they cannot be generic