# How can I check if an array has values for specific positions?

Tags: php, arrays

How can I find out if an array has values for specific positions AND everything else is empty?
Let's say I want to check indexes `2,3,4`
If I have this array:
`10,3,56,78,89,89` returns `false`
if I have `,,45,56,67,,` returns `true`
How can I do this in `PHP`?

Comment: Please **clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need**. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out (considering we're inside of function)

```
$allowed = [2, 3, 4];
$arr = [NULL, NULL, 45, 56, 67, NULL, NULL];
foreach($arr as $k => $v) 
  if(!empty($v) && !in_array($k, $allowed)) return false;
return true;
```

Comment: Note: if you have string like $str = "13,15,,60", explode(",", $str) will convert it into an array

Comment: Thanks, this did it =)

Answer (score 1):

This works well for you.   **[array compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678959/php-check-if-two-arrays-are-equal)**, **[array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/zh/function.array-keys.php)**, **[array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/zh/function.array-filter.php)**

```
return [2,3,4] == array_keys(array_filter($array)) ? true : false;
```