# Check if value are same in two arrays in PHP (even if value is in different order)

Tags: php, arrays

I have a two array's like below:

```
$arr = ["sample","sample2","sample3"];
$arr1 = ["sample3","sample2","sample"];
```

If you notice the above two arrays having same values but in different positions.

I want to check if these two arrays are qual or not ?

I have a below solution but looking for best solution.

```
var_dump((count($arr) == count($arr1) && !array_diff($arr, $arr1)));
```

Please help me with accurate solutions. Thanks !

Comment: [PHP - Check if two arrays are equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678959/php-check-if-two-arrays-are-equal)

Comment: ksort() will sort the keys for you

Answer (score -1):

The only I can think out of the top of my head is.

```
if(  count(array_diff($arr,$arr1)) ){
   print "Array is different";
}else{
   print "Array is the same";
```

Hope it can be of some help.