# How to check if an array has given keys

Tags: php, arrays, validation

From a performance perspective, what is the best way to check whether an associated array has and only has a given set of keys? Same question, but from a code conciseness perspective?

```
function checkArrKeys(array $arr, array $keys):bool {
    $arrKeys=array_keys($arr);
    sort($arrKeys);
    sort($keys);
    return $arrKeys===$keys;
}

function checkArrKeys(array $arr, array $keys):bool {
    return ($cnt = count(array_intersect(array_keys($arr), $keys)))===count($arr) && $cnt===count($keys);
}

function checkArrKeys(array $arr, array $keys):bool {
    return !(array_diff_key($arr, array_flip($keys)) || array_diff_key(array_flip($keys), $arr));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the performance but this is one way.
Merge the keys with the array_keys and count the values.
Then remove all that had the value 2, if something is left there is a difference.

```
$merged = array_diff(array_count_values(array_merge($keys, array_keys($arr))), [2]);
```

https://3v4l.org/ATSHF

Comment: Thanks Andreas.  This doesn't ensure extra keys are passed in `$arr`.

Comment: Found myself doing this differently each time, and want to settle on one approach and stick with it.

Comment: Definitely didn't think of that one! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply, by

```
 function ArrayKeysAreEqual(array $keys, array $arr)
 {
    return array_diff(array_keys($arr), $keys) === array_diff($keys, array_keys($arr)); // return true if matches
 }
```

Comment: Thanks.  Agree it will work, but will be the same as returning true if both are empty.

Comment: yeah, it will return true if both arrays are empty.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`array_diff()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) on this with a [`count()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) check.

```
function checkArrKeys(array $arr, array $keys):bool {
    return count(array_diff(array_keys($arr),$keys)) === 0 && count($keys) === count(array_keys($arr));
}
```

Comment: Thanks vivek_23, but don't think this will ensure that all the keys are passed.

Comment: @user1032531 Didn't get what you mean. Any example?

Comment: What if `$keys` has elements which are not in `$arr`?  Per the docs: Compares array1 against one or more other arrays and returns the values in array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.

Comment: @user1032531 Fixed it. I initially overlooked that as the naming convention is a bit misleading.

Comment: Ah, better.  Similar to my middle example.  I think I like yours more.

Comment: @user1032531 Great.  If you want a fast algorithm performance wise, then you need to check on large arrays.

Answer (score 0):

[Just compare them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5678990/2519416):

```
function checkArrKeys(array $arr, array $keys):bool {
    $arrayKeys = array_keys($arr);
    sort($arrayKeys);

    return $arrayKeys === $keys; // 
}
```

---

```
$a = ['a'=>1, 'b'=>2, 'c'=>3, 'd'=>4];
$A = ['b'=>2, 'c'=>3, 'd'=>4, 'a'=>1];

$b = ['a'=>1, 'b'=>2, 'c'=>3];
$c = ['a'=>1, 'b'=>2, 'c'=>3, 'd'=>4, 'e'=>5];


$keys = ['a','b','c', 'd'];
var_dump(array_keys($a)===$keys); // true
var_dump(array_keys($A)===$keys); // false
var_dump(array_keys($b)===$keys);  // false
var_dump(array_keys($c)===$keys);  // false

function checkArrKeys(array $arr, array $keys):bool {
    $arrayKeys = array_keys($arr);
    sort($arrayKeys);

    return $arrayKeys === $keys; // 
}
echo "\n";

var_dump(checkArrKeys($a, $keys)); // true
var_dump(checkArrKeys($A, $keys)); // true
var_dump(checkArrKeys($b, $keys)); // false
var_dump(checkArrKeys($c, $keys)); // false
```

[Try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/be744a7ce119950623b6007bd2a0b1d5e8c36eb1)

Comment: I don't think it works.  I originally planned on doing the same thing, but the indexes will be different and thus will not be equal.  Hoping I am wrong because I think this is definitely the most readable.

Comment: I've added examples which you can see online

Comment: It works because they happen to be in the same order.  Try changing `$keys` to `['c','b','a', 'd']`

Comment: Yes, which is why I have implemented `sort()`