# how to find the similarity between 2 data if the value is similar if 1 is not 0

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have 2 data in the form of arrays

```
$x  = [ 0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0 ];
$y  = [ 0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0 ];
```

how to determine the similarity value = 1 if X = Y and similarity value = 0 if X ≠ Y

manual example :

1. if 0 is equal to 0 then the result is 1
2. if 1 is equal to 1 then the result is 1
3. if 0 is equal to 1 then the result is 0
4. if 1 is equal to 0 then the result is 0

how to write the program code in the form of an array above ?

please help me.

Comment: `$xeqy = empty(array_diff($x, $y));`?

Comment: You can compare arrays directly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678959/php-check-if-two-arrays-are-equal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP - Check if two arrays are equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678959/php-check-if-two-arrays-are-equal)

Comment: not working in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to get result by checking each value individually try:-

```
function arrayDiff($x, $y){
   return $x==$y ? 1 : 0;
}

$x  = [ 0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0 ];
$y  = [ 0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0 ];

$result=arrayDiff($x[0],$y[0]);
print_r($result);
//results : 1 in this case
```

or if you want the result "in the form of an array" as you have mentioned in your query try:-

```
function myfunction($v1,$v2)
{
    return $v1==$v2 ? 1 : 0;
}

$x  = [ 0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0 ];
$y  = [ 0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0 ];
print_r(array_map("myfunction",$x,$y));
//results : Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 0 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 [4] => 1 [5] => 1 [6] => 1 [7] => 1 [8] => 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

With javascript you can write a function

```
function arrayDiff(x, y){
  if(x==y){
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Call the function like

```
var diff = arrayDiff(X[0], Y[0]);
```

The solution is based on your question as far I can understand

Comment: how to write in php ?

Comment: Hope this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045845/how-to-call-a-javascript-function-from-php