# Check for removed, changed and added elements in array

Tags: php, arrays

I'd like to check, whether an array has been changed compared to another array.

I'd like to get a boolean value for

1. has changed (`true`)
2. has not changed (`false`)

Let's assume this is my original array:

```php
$originalArray = [1,2,3,];
```

Now the boolean should be `true`, if the `$newArray` looks e.g. like:

#### Added item

```php
$newArray = [1,2,3,4];
```

#### Removed item

```php
$newArray = [1,2];
```

#### Different values

```php
$newArray = [1,3,5];
```

### My attempts

```php
$originalArray = [1,2,3,];
$newArray = [1,2,3,4];
array_diff($newArray, $originalArray);
```

This works fine and the result is

```php
[3 => 4,]
```

but for

```php
<?php
  
$originalArray = [1,2,3,];
$newArray = [1,2,];
array_diff($newArray, $originalArray);
```

it does no longer work. I would have to switch `$newArray` and `$originalArray` in `array_diff`.

I think doing something like

```php
$result = count(array_diff($originalArray, $newArray)) === 0 && count(array_diff($newArray, $originalArray)) === 0;
```

is not the best try?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. `array_diff($newArray, $originalArray)` returns the added elements, `array_diff($originalArray, $newArray)` returns the removed elements.

Comment: Okay, so my attempt at the end is not the worst idea?

Comment: If you just want to know if it has changed, just use `$originalArray == $newArray`

Comment: But if the order is allowed to change, you can use `count(array_intersect($newArray, $originalArray)) == count($originalArray)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP - Check if two arrays are equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678959/php-check-if-two-arrays-are-equal)