# assertEquals not comparing array values type?

Tags: php, phpunit, assert

This is a PHPUnit test:

```
class EqualsTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
   public function testSuccess()
   {
      $this->assertEquals(array('01', 'a', 'b'), array(1, 'a', 'b'));
   }
}
```

`'01'` is a string and `1` is an integer but the test is not failling!  `assertEquals` does not comparing types... how to overcome this problem?

Comment: i think assertEquals() works only with the primitives like strings and numbers

Comment: it works on arrays too...

Comment: assertEquals method has an undocumented param $canonicalize. If you use $canonicalize = true, the arrays will be sorted by PHPUnit arrays comparator itself.  $this->assertEquals($array1, $array2, "\$canonicalize = true", $delta = 0.0, $maxDepth = 10, $canonicalize = true);

Comment: check it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838288/phpunit-assert-two-arrays-are-equal-but-order-of-elements-not-important

Comment: but trust me this is not good approach, write your explicit function

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`assertSame` will work in this case.