# PHPUnit assert two multidimensional arrays are equal, but order not important

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, phpunit, associative-array

I'm having these two arrays

```
$expectedArray = [
   'mainKey1' => [
       'subKey1.1' => 'Value 1',
       'subKey1.2' => 'Value 2',
       'subKey1.3' => 'Value 3',
   ],
   'mainKey2' => [
       'subKey2.1' => 'Value 21',
       'subKey2.2' => 'Value 22',
       'subKey2.3' => 'Value 23',
   ],
];

$outputArray = [
   'mainKey1' => [
       'subKey1.1' => 'Value 1',
       'subKey1.2' => 'Value 2',
       'subKey1.3' => 'Value 3',
   ],
   'mainKey2' => [
       'subKey2.1' => 'Value 21',
       'subKey2.2' => 'Value 22',
       'subKey2.3' => 'Value 23',
   ],
];
```

I'm using the same function as here [PHPUnit: assert two arrays are equal, but order of elements not important](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838288/phpunit-assert-two-arrays-are-equal-but-order-of-elements-not-important) so

```
function arrays_are_similar($a, $b) {
  // if the indexes don't match, return immediately
  if (count(array_diff_assoc($a, $b))) {
    return false;
  }
  // we know that the indexes, but maybe not values, match.
  // compare the values between the two arrays
  foreach($a as $k => $v) {
    if ($v !== $b[$k]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  // we have identical indexes, and no unequal values
  return true;
}
```

but this returns me an error `[PHPUnit\Framework\Exception] Array to string conversion`

Any ideas what Im doing wrong?

Comment: `array_diff_assoc` compares __values as strings__. It's written in the manual, btw.

Comment: You should take a look at this: https://gist.github.com/pokap/ac5fce3570c9bec3a87a8908bcbd0bbc

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you need the function for (because the order of the elements of both arrays is identical) and also not what you do with PHPUnit.
With PHP you can use === to check whether two arrays are identical.

```
$expectedArray = [
   'mainKey1' => [
       'subKey1.1' => 'Value 1',
       'subKey1.2' => 'Value 2',
       'subKey1.3' => 'Value 3',
   ],
   'mainKey2' => [
       'subKey2.1' => 'Value 21',
       'subKey2.2' => 'Value 22',
       'subKey2.3' => 'Value 23',
   ],
];

$outputArray = [
   'mainKey1' => [
       'subKey1.1' => 'Value 1',
       'subKey1.2' => 'Value 2',
       'subKey1.3' => 'Value 3',
   ],
   'mainKey2' => [
       'subKey2.1' => 'Value 21',
       'subKey2.2' => 'Value 22',
       'subKey2.3' => 'Value 23',
   ],
];

var_dump($outputArray === $expectedArray);  //bool(true)
```

Check this by changing a little something in an array and you will get bool(false) as result.