# PHP Sorting Objects

Tags: php

```
    [sections] => stdClass Object
            (
                [22353] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [section_start_date] => 1410235200
                    )

                [22354] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [section_start_date] => 1410235260

                    )
)
```

How do I sort the above objects in PHP by the id, while preserving the keys of the sections object? For instance I want to show 22354 on top of 22353. Since these are objects the keys are technically just strings to me but I need to keep them in tact.

There is some confusion going on. These are objects which are not in an array. Pay close attention to the section object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort Object in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124266/sort-object-in-php)

Comment: This is what you're looking for:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282413/sort-array-of-objects-by-object-fields

Comment: These are objects which are not in a collection like an array.

Comment: you are right but does not make sense ordering object properties ... IMHO i see it like a bad design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how you do it

```
stdClass Object
(
    [111111] => stdClass Object
        (
           [id] => 2
           [section_start_date] => 1410235200
       )
    [999999] => stdClass Object
       (
            [id] => 1
            [section_start_date] => 1410235260
       )

    [222222] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [section_start_date] => 1410235300
    )
    [555555] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [section_start_date] => 1410231160
        )
)
```

Steps 
Convert stdClass to array

```
$data = json_decode(json_encode($object),true);
ksort($data);
print_r($data);
```

output new sorted array while maintaining key index.

```
Array
(
    [111111] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [section_start_date] => 1410235200
        )
    [222222] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [section_start_date] => 1410235300
        )
    [555555] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [section_start_date] => 1410231160
        )
    [999999] => Array
        (
           [id] => 1
           [section_start_date] => 1410235260
        )
)
```